# phing toString method with fileset

Tags: phing

Phing's documentation shows an example that should display a list all php files of a certain folder using a fileset with an id of "sourcefiles":

https://www.phing.info/guide/chunkhtml/ch04s02.html
(See 4.2.4)

So I put together a build-xml with this task:

```xml
<project default="countFile">
    <property name="BUILD_DIR" value="./buildTest"/>
    <target name="dist" depends="build">
        <fileset id="sourcefiles" dir="${BUILD_DIR}">
            <include name="./*.*" />
        </fileset>
        <echo>files in build dir: ${toString:sourcefiles}</echo>
        <echo>build dir: ${BUILD_DIR}</echo>
        <echo>OS: ${os.name}</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

I also tried the one-liner version from the documentation: `<fileset id="sourcefiles" dir=".build" includes="**/*.txt"/>`.

However, the output is nothing else but exactly that dollar-curly-brace-text as text: '${toString:sourcefiles}' instead of its interpolated result.

[image: phing: toString method not interpolated]

What would be the proper way to right it? Is this an error in the docs?
(I am not new to deployment, but new to phing.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `include` element inside your fileset has a non valid pattern. From the [documentation](https://www.phing.info/guide/hlhtml/#FileSet)

> In patterns, one asterisk (*) maps to a part of a file/directory name within a
> directory level. Two asterisks (**) may include above the "border" of the directory
> separator.

Your example becomes:

```xml
<project default="countFile">
    <property name="BUILD_DIR" value="./buildTest"/>
    <target name="dist" depends="build">
        <fileset id="sourcefiles" dir="${BUILD_DIR}">
            <include name="*.*" />
        </fileset>
        <echo>files in build dir: ${toString:sourcefiles}</echo>
        <echo>build dir: ${BUILD_DIR}</echo>
        <echo>OS: ${os.name}</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

And will output something like:

```
Buildfile: C:\Users\XXX\test\build.xml
[autoloader] Loading autoloader from C:\Users\XXX\test/bootstrap.php
      [php] Evaluating PHP expression: ini_set('error_reporting', -1);
      [php] Evaluating PHP expression: ini_set('memory_limit', -1);
      [php] Evaluating PHP expression: ini_set('date.timezone', 'UTC');

Phing Build Tests > test:

     [echo] files in build dir: bootstrap.php;build.xml;phpunit-sparse.xml;phpunit.xml

BUILD FINISHED

Total time: 0.4785 seconds



Build finished at 30.11.2020 23:19 with exit code 0.
```

Also note that the `${toString:XXX}` feature is only available for phing 3.x

Comment: I missed out that the guide is for version 3! Thank you for pointing that out to me!